# No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.2 in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow1.15

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

2.9.2

```
pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install tensorflow==1.15.2
```

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.2 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.2

I used to use these libraries below by using tensorflow 1.15.2 in Google Colab. I could use pip install tensorflow 1.15.2 back in the days.  But I cannot pip install tensorflow 1.15.2 anymore. I want to use these libraries below, how can I use them in Google Colab?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
from tensorflow.contrib import legacy_seq2seq
```

Comment: `Tensorflow 1.x` is no longer supported in `Google Colab` and deprecated to use since `Aug 1, 2022`. It is recommended to use the latest tensorflow version in the `Tensorflow 2.x` series. Please check this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#migrate-from-tensorflow-1x-to-tensorflow-2) to convert your `TF 1.x` code to run in `TF 2.x`. Also, have a look at the mentioned links to access above [RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN) and [seq2seq](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq) apis in `TF 2.x`.